# How to find and replace text in text file using php?

Tags: php

i need to find a line and change it to whatever user will type in input i didnt write this code pls help

```
<?php
$myfile = 'test.txt';
$lines = file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines[4] = $_POST['title'];
file_put_contents($myFile , implode("\n", $lines));
?>
```

i tryed lot of ways but non of them works and i only have this code . i am working on project idea is simple user will give type url of website i need to find a line and change it to `<form action="process.php" method="post">` i need help its will be on same line so i dont need to change line
i searched lot of ways but does not works for me.
i am starter at php so...

Comment: Typo: `$myfile` vs `$myFile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your code.

```
$lines = file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

should be

```
$lines = file($myfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

because you're declaring
`$myfile = 'test.txt';`

*Note the usage of smaller case `f` in file name.*

#### Now, coming to your question.

You want to replace some lines in the file with user input.

Let's assume that you want to replace the text `THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED`.
For that, you could use the code something line below:

```
<?PHP
$myfile = './test.txt';
$lines = file($myfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$textToBeReplaced = "THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED";

$index = array_search($textToBeReplaced, $lines);
if (false !== $index) {
    $lines[$index] = $_POST['title'] ?? '';
}
file_put_contents($myFile , implode("\n", $lines));
?>
```